# creating cartoon explosions like in jetpack squad

Tags: unity, graphics

I followed this excellent tutorial for creating volumetric explosions: https://stevencraeynest.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/easy-volumetric-explosion-in-unity3d/

I get the explosions as the tutorial mentioned, however, I noticed that jetpack squad does a similar technique but has getting much nicer cloud formations.  My Question is, what kind of noise texture would I have to use to get a more cartoony explosion cloud like in jetpack squad vs the tutorial

[image: jetpack squad explosion]

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://www.alkemi-games.com/a-game-of-tricks-iii-particles-fun-part1/ and http://www.alkemi-games.com/a-game-of-tricks-v-particles-fun-part2/
If this looks like what you're after, I or someone else can attempt to expand it from a comment + link into a full answer...

Comment: @Pikalek this is excellent! I read through but my limiting factor is still generating the appropriate texture to emulate the very billowy clouds

Answer (score 1):

#### Short answer

Simplify your textures.

#### Longer Answer

First, simplify, or blur, your displacement map. One way of doing this is to generate the displacement maps with a lower resolution. Then, scale it up, using interpolation, to the original dimensions. This will simplify the shape of the explosion. It should end up looking more like the second image, and less like the first: (original image from provided link):

[image: Original displacement texture][image: New displacement texture]

This will make your explosion look less *detailed*.

---

Second, simplify your ramp texture so that it looks more like this:
[image]

This will make your explosion look less *smooth*, since there are essentially only two color values (besides the gradient in the middle).

#### Conclusion

Simplifying your textures creates a more cartoony explosion, since cartoons are really just simplified graphics, right?